# How is the R-Tree's MBR size determined? Changes to MBR?

Tags: database-theory, databases

The R-Tree creates 'rectangles' to index 2D data. How is their size calculated exactly? What happens to the performance by changing this parameter i.e. the size of this rectangle/MBR? Number of overlaps, area covered change but can this speed up some kind of queries or build a smaller index?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you are asking.  What parameter are you referring to?  Can you edit the question to expand or elaborate on what you are asking?

Comment: I am still familiarising myself with the field but... Rtree indexes 2D data by creating rectangles over the data. There are many techniques with which to 'cover' the data, some prioritise reducing dead/empty space, others focus on reducing overlaps and so on... So we have parameters to an Rtree such as dead space, size of boxes, overlaps which affect performance and I am trying to implement some kind of test on this idea.

Comment: Got it.  Some thoughts for the future: This site's format works better if you've read enough that you can formulate a specific, focused question.  I'm worried that this question might be a bit vague/open-ended, which isn't ideal for our site's format (see our [help/dont-ask]).  Or maybe that's just my ignorance; perhaps someone who is more expert in the area than me will find it clearer what is being asked.  Anyway, take that as feedback that might be helpful if you ask any other questions in the future.  And welcome to CS.SE!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let us have some background. There are variants of Guttman's r-tree that have different splitting heuristics (e.g. Sellis' r+-tree, which involves inserting an item multiple times into a tree; and Beckmann's r*-tree, which takes into account area, margin, overlap). Also, there are variants that are more suitable for higher dimensions (e.g. Berchtold's x-tree, which uses split history and supernodes). You can improve any of the above structures using bulk loading, which can guarantee zero overlap between rectangles at the same level.

Rectangles used typically are minimum bounding rectangles (MBR's) that may fit your data well (if you are using orthonormal rectangles as with data mining), or may have to be used as approximations (if you are trying to detect intersections between polytopes).

You can find MBR's, which are possibly described using upper-left point and lower-right point, by taking extreme value pairs for each dimension.

Note also that points are degenerate rectangles and that we can form MBR's for collections of MBR's.

For example, if we had $P$ = $\{(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3)\}$, and right is large $x$ and up is large $y$, an MBR for these points could be $(p_\text{upper-left}, p_\text{lower-right})$ = $((1, 3), (4, 0))$.

There have been attempts to quantify how much time a query on an r-tree takes, but intuitively what is happening is that we may spend more than $O(k \cdot \log(n))$ time for $k$ matches, even though depth is $O(\log(n))$, because we could go down many branches without reaching a match. If you are interested, there are certain operations one could perform on an r-tree that take more time but have clean running time asymptotic values if you include a "look-ahead" query at each node we visit. In the end, however, with a regular r-tree and with regular queries, loosening the MBR's leads to diminished performance.

Comment: Thanks for a very insightful post. Could you provide some more insights on how loosening the MBR leads to diminished performance or refer me to some relevant material? You make reference to regular queries, does this mean that one can expect some improvement on some other queries?